# Finding the inverse of $y=c_1(x-c_2)^{c_3}+c_4(x-c_5)^{c_6}$ or $y=c_1(x-c_2)^{c_3}+c_4(x-c_5)^{c_6}+c_7(x-c_8)^{c_9}$, with each $c_i$ real

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am able to inverse simple functions like:

$$y= c_1(x-c_2)^{c_3}$$
every $c_i$ represents a real number.

Where the inverse would be:

$$x=\left(\frac{y}{c_1}\right)^{1/c_3}+c_2$$

But I cannot figure out how to invert longer equations which exist of the same building blocks, like:

$$y=c_1(x-c_2)^{c_3}+c_4(x-c_5)^{c_6}$$
or
$$y=c_1(x-c_2)^{c_3}+c_4(x-c_5)^{c_6}+c_7(x-c_8)^{c_9}$$
where every $c_i$ represents a real number.

Is there anyone which could help out? Thank you in advance!

Kind regards,
Jonas

Comment: Consider $y=x^2$ as a very simple example that you cant invert as for every $y$ there are two different $x$ that fulfill the equation. So what exactly do you mean with inverse?

Comment: This can't be done. Even in the simpler case where $c_3$ and $c_6$ are positive integers, the problem turns into solving a polynomial equation of high degree which don't have a general solution.

Comment: Thank you both for replying. I really appreciate this! Perhaps I am looking for something which is not possible. What I want to achieve is to be able to calculate an x-value with a given y-value. Is that possible? Thanks in advance!